# My first applet shows nothing

Tags: java, applet

I am trying to run this applet code below.But When I run it .I  just get an empty Applet screen that says applet started.

```
public class Ass extends JApplet{
    double sum;
    public void init(){
        double  D1=Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("firstvAL"));
        double D2=Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("secondvAL"));
        sum=D1+D2;
    }

    @Override
    public void print(Graphics g) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.print(g);
        g.drawString("Sum is"+sum,44,44);
    }

}
```

And I want to ask one more thing.I have removed eclips ide and downloaded Enterprice edition .And noticed  these two section .Why is that? did I make a mistake while removing eclipse folder

[image]

Comment: show your `main` method

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be using `paint ( )` instead of `print ( )` .